# Group lines from a file by a certain char limit using Streams

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-stream, java.nio.file

I am new to Java 8 Stream API and was having trouble using it in the following scenario :

I have to read a file line by line and group lines in a manner that their size reaches closest to a certain character limit and then publish it to Kafka.

```
    public void publishStringToKafka(File outputFile) {
        try {
            Files.lines(outputFile.toPath())
                    .forEach(s -> kafkaProducer.publishMessageOnTopic(s, KAFKA_INGESTION_TOPIC));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Could not read buffered file to send message on kafka.", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(outputFile.toPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("Problem in deleting the buffered file {}.", outputFile.getName(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am completely comfortable doing this using the conventional or declartive style  i.e. read a file line by line, combine them using a loop and keep publishing the message on kafka on when the size is closest to say 1024 characters. 
But I wanted to use streams for this.

Note : I am facing another issue with this piece of code which is , `Files.deleteIfExists(outputFile.toPath());` command does not delete the file after the execution and no exception takes place. Whereas if I use declarative style then the file is deleted successfully.

Please help.

Comment: I posted a solution for your main question. Maybe you can move the question of the Files.deleteIfExists problem to another post, since it is unrelated to the main question.

Comment: You don’t close the `Stream`, so you shouldn’t be surprised if deleting the source file doesn’t work.

Comment: @Holger so is this what I should do : `Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(outputPath);stream.forEach(System.out::println);stream.close();`

Comment: No, you should do `try( Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(outputPath) ) { stream.forEach(System.out::println);‌ }`. You can even chain the `finally { Files.deleteIfExists(…); }` body to it.

Comment: alright try-with-resources, nice suggestion, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem statement** What you want to do is combine all the strings in the stream, in order, to as close to a maximum amount of characters and create a new List of them. This newly created list can then be used to stream to Kafka. This is not an easy problem to solve, since you have to deal with state.

**Solution**

Use a `Collector` to accumulate the values

```
 List<String> result = someStrings.stream()
                                  .collect(ArrayList::new, (list, string) -> accumulate(list, string), List::addAll);
```

The `accumulate` method contains the maximum character logic:

```
 private void accumulate(ArrayList<String> list, String string) {
        if (list.isEmpty() || list.get(list.size() -1).length() + string.length() > MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS){
            list.add(string);
        } else {
            list.set(list.size()-1, list.get(list.size()-1) + string);
        }
    }
```

If you input the list [as, 1234, 213, bd, de] with a MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS set to 5, it will return the desired output [as, 1234, 213bd, de].

Comment: Note that there is `Collector.of` which allows to create a collector with just the three function, which is much simpler than a custom implementation of that interface. You could also just use the handy three-arg `collect` method right on a stream. Further, the accumulator function is unnecessarily complicated, having two conditionals with identical actions. The logic should be “if not empty and last+new small enough, replace the last, otherwise just add the new”. Further, `remove(lastIndex); add(newValue);` can be replaced by `set(lastIndex, newValue);`.

Comment: @Holger Updated the answer. Should I delete the long version? Or does it contain valuable information for the reader?

Comment: Note that `(list, string) -> { accumulate(list, string); }` can be simplified to `(list, string) -> accumulate(list, string)` or even a method reference. Whether you keep the long version, is your decision, but since it lacks a combiner, which isn’t so obvious in such a big code, I wouldn’t keep it. By the way, when you use the three-arg version of `Stream.collect(…)`, you can use `List::addAll` as combiner. This isn’t entirely correct (there is no correct solution anyway), but at least, you don’t loose strings with that.

Comment: thanx a lott for such a good explanation :D, I guess I'll have to read more about lambdas and streams !!

Comment: @Furquan Ahmed: start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description).

Comment: I changed it to the `Stream.collect(...)` method since I liked the idea of the `List::addAll`. Always wonder if the code looks cleaner if I put the arguments on their own line or not. I prefer the inline lambda notation for the accumulate, for some reason I don't like return values like `BiConsumer<ArrayList<String>, String>` in code that's not in 'framework'.

Comment: @Holger nice link to start from, I'd usually refer people to one of Venkat's talks or something like that

Answer (score 2):

The `Collectors.groupingBy()` will be useful in this case.

```
Map<T, List<String>> result = Files.lines(outputFile.toPath())
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Your::classifier, Collectors.toList()))
```

As a result, you get a `Map<T,List<String>>`. `T` is the type returned by Your::classifier. Now you already have everything grouped and can proceed with the for-each.

Now you can extract an entry set, sort it, flatMap it, and publish to Kafka. `flatMap` is necessary because if you do not flatten your structure, you end up iterating `Stream<List<>>`. This does not need to be a bad thing but I assumed this is not the desired situation.

```
 collect.entrySet().stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
   .forEach(s -> kafkaProducer.publishMessageOnTopic(s, KAFKA_INGESTION_TOPIC));
```

The only tricky part is implementing the classifier method appropriately but from the question I understood that you know how to do this.

Comment: What your code does, sort the lines by a property, can be done entirely without that grouping step. You can chain a `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Your::classifier))` right to the `Files.lines`, append a `forEachOrdered` and you’re done. Whether this is what the OP wants, is another story.

Comment: Btw, you can use [`Map.Entry.comparingByKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey--) here.